# How to create a backup using SMO and place it for download in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database-backups, smo

I want to create a backup a specific database and then add to the stream so that it can be immediately downloaded by the browser. Here's my code:

```
public void BackUpMyDB(Page webPage)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect))
            {
                ServerConnection srvConn = new ServerConnection(con);
                Server srvr = new Server(srvConn);

                if (srvr != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Backup bkpDatabase = new Backup();
                        bkpDatabase.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
                        bkpDatabase.Database = databaseName;
                        string fileName = "BackUp_" + (DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '.')) + ".bak";
                        string fullPath = webPage.Server.MapPath(BACKUP_FOLDER + fileName);
                        BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(fullPath, DeviceType.File);
                        bkpDatabase.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
                        bkpDatabase.SqlBackup(srvr);

                        //add the file to the stream

                        webPage.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                        webPage.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                        webPage.Response.TransmitFile(webPage.Server.MapPath(fullPath));
                        webPage.Response.End();

                    }
                    catch 
                    {
                        //error
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is since the backup takes some time and the `Responce.TransmitFile` wants to add the file to the stream immediately, the stream only gets like 6kb of the backup file and the browser downloads only a small useless file (although the backup is created successfully in the desired path).

So I decided to change the code to this by adding an event handler:

```
public void BackUpMyDB(Page webPage)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect))
            {
                ServerConnection srvConn = new ServerConnection(con);
                Server srvr = new Server(srvConn);

                if (srvr != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Backup bkpDatabase = new Backup();
                        bkpDatabase.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
                        bkpDatabase.Database = databaseName;
                        string fileName = "BackUp_" + (DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '.')) + ".bak";
                        string fullPath = webPage.Server.MapPath(BACKUP_FOLDER + fileName);
                        BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(fullPath, DeviceType.File);
                        bkpDatabase.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
                        bkpDatabase.SqlBackup(srvr);
                        bkpDatabase.PercentCompleteNotification = 2;

                        bkpDatabase.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler((o, e) =>
                        {
                            //add the file to the stream
                            if (e.Percent == 100)
                            {
                                webPage.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                                webPage.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                                webPage.Response.TransmitFile(webPage.Server.MapPath(fullPath));
                                webPage.Response.End();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch 
                    {
                        ClientSide.ShowAlert(AlertConstants.Header.OP_ERROR, AlertConstants.Message.DB_ERROR, AlertType.ERROR);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But the eventhandler is not firing at all and nothing will be put to the stream.(I also tried using the `Complete` event but still it is the same).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try invoking `bkpDatabase.Wait()` before sending out the file.

Comment: tried your solution, still the same thing happens

Comment: You can NOT wait for the backup to complete... you must start the job, and update the page from time to time to see if the final file is there and exist and ready to download, OR to send an email with the link to download after the job complete

Comment: you mean I can't make the progress event handlers to work in webforms?